# PostGIS Docker root Access

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postgis, root, startupscript

How to build postgis container as root user using `docker-compose up`?

In Dockerfile, separate attempts to set `USER` to `root` as well `0` did not work.

Updating docker-compose service with `user: '0'` was tried to no avail.

There error I am getting is `Permission denied`.

The `id -u` is always running as `999` during the build.  This seems to be a system user with limited privilege.

I would prefer to just run `docker-compose up` with no flags and keep all configurations in `docker-compose.yml` and/or `Dockerfile`.

Dockerfile

```
FROM postgis/postgis:13-3.3
USER root
COPY ./startup.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/startup.sh
```

**NOTE:**

I realized that I should have added more context.  I created another post that better describes the issue.

[Open SSH tunnel during PostGIS Docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74855870/open-ssh-tunnel-during-postgis-docker-build)

Answer (score 0):

Please be carefull with root, it can inject vulnerabilities in your database.
I highly recommend to you to use it only for development.

You can run this command below:

```
docker-compose up --user root
```

Or put it in your docker-compose file:

```
services:
  postgis:
    user: root
```

Comment: Much appreciation for your answer.  However this did not work for my use case.  I realize I may not have given the all the proper context.  I thought mentioning PostGIS was enough.  I have created another post that give more context and code snippets.  Would you take a look at that one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74855870/open-ssh-tunnel-during-postgis-docker-build.  Thanks!